# Javascript ifinite loop( Greensock)

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, gsap

I am wondering  how is it possible to make infinite animations for example in GreenSock JavaScript library. I know that JavaScript can make only 1 operation at the time, but I want some SVG images to move non stop. For me it looks like infinite loop but I know that I think in wrong way somwhere. I would like to know how this kind of things work under the hood but I can't find good resources.

Comment: Checkout [`RequestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Try using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957759/animated-output-based-on-single-input-field/42958342#42958342

Comment: You have tagged GreenSock and indicated GreenSock in the question title. The documentation for GreenSock's [TimelineMax.repeat()](https://greensock.com/docs/TimelineMax/repeat()) states: "Gets or sets the number of times that the timeline should repeat after its first iteration. ... To repeat indefinitely, use -1."

Answer (score 1):

The Greensock animation platform has two classes that allow infinite loops, TweenMax and TimelineMax.

If you want all your elements to animate at the same time in an endless loop you can use TweenMax and pass the elements as an array:

```
const myObjects = [...];
const t = TweenMax.to(myObjects, 1, {rotation:360, ease:Linear.easeNone, repeat:-1});
// this creates a seamless rotation of all the objects at the same time
```

Now If you want to create a more complex sequence you should use TimelineMax:

```
const tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});
// then add the instances to the timeline
tl
  .to(object1, 1, {rotation:360, ease:Linear.easeNone})
  .to(object2, 1, {x:200});
  // and so on
```

Now if you wan to overlap you can play with the position parameter in order to create better looking animations: https://greensock.com/position-parameter

Also you can use the stagger methods to create overlapping animations with the same properties: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/exGbj?editors=0010

Finally is worth noticing that the stagger method will animate the same property to all the elements while using the timeline class with the position parameter allows you to create a different animation for each object.

Comment: great answer. I would just like to add that you might end up having a memory leak or other js issues if you use repeat incorrectly. Make sure your code is sound enough to handle the exceptions.
That being said, it would be better to use css animation for infinite loop

Comment: Greensock works great in terms of GC and every instance is only created once. I've made and seen many samples using repeat:-1 and don't remember any memory leaks because of that. Care to share a code that causes memory leaks?, in order to report that as an issue to greensock and they can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use timeline. As long as you are using TweenMax you can do.

`TweenMax.to(mc, 1, {x:100, repeat:-1});`

If you want the tween to bounce back and forward you can do

`TweenMax.to(mc, 1, {x:100, repeat:-1, yoyo:true});`